# Buttons inside iOS top safe area?

Tags: ios, button, statusbar, safearealayoutguide

I can't find any info about it at all. In my case:

- no status bar
- portrait mode only
- 2 buttons in the top device corners

Can these buttons overlap the top safe area on iPhone X-like devices?

Comment: Are you asking **CAN** they overlap? Or **SHOULD** they overlap? If you're asking if they *can*, then sure... just constrain them to the superview instead of to the safe-area.

Comment: I ask *CAN* - I didn't find any info that Apple restricts that for the top area when status bar is not visible